# How can I use media-queries to load a javascript file from HTML

Tags: javascript, media-queries

Is it possible (and if so how) to have a media query load a different javascript file from the HTML depending on browser size?

something along the lines of this?

```
<script media="screen and (max-width: 900px)" src="/js/menu_home.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or something like this as I found on the internet but it didn't load either file

```
<script>
function require(path) {
  try{
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+path+'"><\/script>');
  } catch(e) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = path;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
}
if (isMedia("screen and (max-width:900px)"){
  require('/js/menu_home.js');
}
else {
  require('/js/menu_photo.js');
}
</script>
```

On my website http://www.kujawadesigns.com/web/where_art_thou/ I have it set up to load different script files to allow the accordion menu to be expanded on the right category. I would like to always have the expandfirst class removed from the mobile version however. If you guys would recommend I use another process, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Using **matchmedia** you can execute blocks of JavaScript only when a certain mediaquery condition is met

```
<script>
    if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 600px)')){
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      s = document.createElement('script');
      s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
      s.setAttribute('src',jsname);
      head.insertBefore(s, head.firstChild);


    }
</script>
```

Reference: http://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries/

Note:
For older/unsupported web browsers, you can try the matchMedia() polyfill, although it doesn’t support addListener.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It seems that it should work. However the </script> tag is closing itself.

I tried doing something like this but it still won't work.
`
<script>
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 900px)')){
document.write('<script src="/js/menu_home.js" type="text/javascript"></scr'+'ipt>');
}
else {
document.write('<script src="/js/menu_photo.js" type="text/javascript"></scr'+'ipt>');
}
</script>
`
sorry I am new to javascript and don't quite understand it yet.

Comment: sorry for the syntax in the comment. I cant figure out how to change that portion to code view. It should just be `code` right? weird that it did not work on the other comment.

Comment: append a script to head using javascript, i mistakenly type document.write